# How to know the working copy of someone else?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am in a project with some people. I would like to know what working copy a person is without going to his computer. Is it possible? How?

Comment: 1. it should not matter (and hey, they could have more than one...) 2. not possible without searching their entire computer. The server knows nothing about working copies.

Comment: Best way is to go to the developer's desk and ask to see what they're working on.  Take it as an opportunity to pair-program on the task.  Aside from that, SVN itself doesn't provide this functionality.  You'd probably have to remotely access their workstation's file system via the OS functionality.

Comment: Why do you think you need this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the commenters have stated, you cannot without access to their computer. Every working copy is separate and distinct, and WCs are not tracked by the server or any other mechanism.